# High volume large file uploads

Tags: file, upload

Trying to find a suitable method of accepting large file uploads that has to be scalable. By large I mean up to 5-10gb files.

I also need to process the files afterwards. I was thinking of using PHP and HTTP PUT for uploads, then passing the stream of data directly to disk. I'd then process the file afterwards.

Doing a custom server and protocol would be my second attempt but I'd like to avoid that.

I'll also be implementing a custom desktop upload client, so would HTTP PUT be good for that too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem with HTTP POST? Is webserver trying to stuff the gigabytes into memory rather than to disk, or some limit of PHP, or ...?

Comment: I know with POST PHP has max post limits. It's not really suited to that. With PUT at least with PHP I can stream the files onto disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP would be too fragile for that and usually client uploads are a lot slower which doesn't help.

You'd be better off using some other method to upload big files like using [flash](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=flash+file+uploader), [Java](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+file+uploader) or perhaps [Silverligth](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=silverlight+file+uploader) ;-)

Comment: If I use Silverlight, what protocol do I use? Wouldn't I still use HTTP? What do I have on the server side?

Keep in mind with HTTP PUT + PHP I can implement upload resume on the server side.

Comment: I decided to go with a Java upload client using HTTP PUT method and some hash checking and some extra stuff to allow resuming/pausing of the upload.

Comment: Which specific product did you choose?